# How to arrange Intellij IDEA tools windows?

Tags: intellij-idea

Am new to Intellij IDEA. Earlier I used eclipse and Visual Studio.
I want to simultaneously view Project and Structure windows like this:

[image]

All I can do currently is this:

[image]

So I have Project and Structure windows docked side by side. However I want to dock/stack the vertically, one above other.

**Q1.** According to [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/viewing-modes.html#d1516201e240) link, I have to keep split mode on for one and off for other to make them stack one above other. However this is not working for me. What I am missing?

**Q2.** Also is it possible to have tabbed windows like in eclipse:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that only one should have the "Split Mode" option enabled, but under Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance, you have the "Side-by-side layout on the left" option enabled.

As for the tabs, simply turn off the "Group Tabs" option.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be running into [IDEA-159015](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-159015) which reports problems with split mode in v2016.2. Although the title of the issue indicates it is in an EAP version, in the comments, people are reporting it against released versions.

Answer (score 0):

In case if tool windows are not appearing at the bottom try this. Go to
Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance -> Tool Windows(The last one) -> Check the option "Tool Window bars"