# List of methods IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm new to IntelliJ, coming from NetBeans. In NetBeans, on the bottom left side of the window, under the list of files in the project, there is a list of methods/fields in the current class.

With IntelliJ, I found that same window using CTRL+F12, but it's a popup. I'd like it to sit permanently on the bottom left instead. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to arrange Intellij IDEA tools windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229334/how-to-arrange-intellij-idea-tools-windows)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can open it by `View->Tools windows->Structure`
[image]

Alternatively you can press ALT+7 (Tested on Ubuntu).

Comment: To add to thins answer, the "Structure" tool window can/will show properties, fields, and lambdas in addition to methods. You can configure it as to what it shows. You can also configure it as to whether it shows private items or just public. And whether it shows inherited items or not. And finally, there is both a scroll to source and source from source option. So be sure to play around with the settings. And like all tool windows, it can be moved, pinned, floated, etc.

Comment: Do you happen to know if it can be setup to auto-expand the region you are in? For example if I'm looking at the method "foo", I'd like it to be expanded in the structure tab, and everything else collapsed.

Comment: @CLOVIS I did not hear about this kind of feature.

Comment: Found it, it's "auto-scroll from source" in the structure tab's settings

Answer (score 5):

ALT+7 (⌘7 on Mac) shall show up `Structure` which lists all the methods of current class open in editor.

You can get familiar with IntelliJ IDEA from this [official tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/discover-intellij-idea.html)